# Replace text in WordPress+ACF reapter field via functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, function, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have a problem, I wanted to use functions to the options acf page called 'translation_slow' to add the possibility on a reapter field basis to change the content using the following function:

```
function multi_change_translate_text( $translated ) {
    $text       = array(
        'Old Text 1' => 'New Text 1',
    );
    $translated = str_ireplace( array_keys( $text ), $text, $translated );
    return $translated;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'multi_change_translate_text', 20 );
```

I tried to write it as follows :

```
// Translate Strings

function multi_change_translate_text( $translated ) {
    $text = array();

    $repeater_values = get_field('tlumaczenie_slow', 'option');

    foreach($repeater_values as $value) {

        $old_text = $value['old_text'];
        $new_text = $value['new_text'];

        $text[$old_text] = $new_text;
    }

    $translated = str_ireplace( array_keys( $text ), $text, $translated );
    return $translated;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'multi_change_translate_text', 20 );
```

However, something is wrong because I have a critical error/white page after applying this code. Someone please direct me where I have gone wrong?

Comment: can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: @Moishy full white page without nothing

Comment: Enable WP debug mode then, and go check what the error log has to say.

Comment: debug mode not working, blank page without any code in cosole

Comment: gonna need to see some sort of error to help you

Comment: @Moishy, i make backup in new hosting, other hosting show error with this code "Service Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later."

Comment: [Tue Dec 13 19:24:03.102217 2022] [lsapi:error] [pid 10764:tid 140369547204352] [client 178.235.190.85:49486] [host xxxxx.pl] Error on sending request(GET / HTTP/1.0); uri(/) content-length(0): ReceiveAckHdr: nothing to read from backend (LVE ID 1137), check http://docs.cloudlinux.com/mod_lsapi_troubleshooting.html

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
function multi_change_translate_text( $translated ) {

    if ( is_admin() ) return $translated;

    $text = array();

    if ( have_rows( 'tlumaczenie_slow', 'options' ) ) {
        while ( have_rows( 'tlumaczenie_slow', 'options' ) ) {
            the_row();
            $old_text = get_sub_field( 'old_text' );
            $new_text = get_sub_field( 'new_text' );
            if ( $old_text && $new_text ) {
                $text[ $old_text ] = $new_text;
            }
            $translated = str_ireplace( array_keys( $text ), $text, $translated );
        }
    }

    return $translated;
}

add_filter( 'gettext', 'multi_change_translate_text', 20, 1 );
```

Comment: With debug mode i see this error: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare multi_change_translate_text() (previously declared in /home/xxx/functions.php:174) in /home/xxx/functions.php on line 192